# Cannot redirect IO using popen

Tags: python, subprocess, io-redirection

I cannot use output redirect in using `Popen`. Here's the problematic code:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['program'
                  'arg', #arguments
                  '0',
                  '&> program.out'])
```

The program runs, but the `stdout` and `stderr` doesn't get routed to the output file. Furthermore, the last argument was concatenated with the redirect command as a single argument (`0&> program.out` in this case). When I join the commands together and pass the whole command string to Popen, with `shell=True`, things go smoothly, but I think this might not the recommended way to use `Popen`.

Answer (score 1):

`&> filename` syntax is Bourne shell (e.g. bash) syntax, you'd probably want to do something closer to:

```
with open('program.out', 'w') as fd:
  subprocess.Popen(['program', 'arg'], stdout=fd, stderr=fd)
```

as per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for `stdout` and `stderr`:

> Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None.

where the code above is just passing "an existing file object"